# how to sync different model in angular

Tags: angularjs

```
<input ng-model='yourName'>
<p>{{yourName}}</p>
```

when I type some words in the input `yourName`, the `<p>` will display what I typed immediately.

===

If I need do some sync in different model,
eg.

```
 <input ng-model='start'>
 <input ng-model='end'>
 <input ng-model='step'>,default 10.
```

when I changed the model `start` to `1`, it automatically update the model `end` to `11`,**vice versa**.

what should I do?
**this problem is solved.just add `type="number"`, thanks**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller='MyController'>
        <input type="number" ng-model="start">
        <input type="number" ng-model="end">
        <input type="number" ng-model="step">

<script>
    function MyController($scope){
        $scope.$watch('start',function(newStart){
            $scope.end = newStart + $scope.step;
            console.log(1);
        })  ;
        $scope.$watch('end',function(newEnd){
            $scope.start = newEnd - $scope.step;
            console.log(2);
        })  ;

        $scope.step = 10;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post your controller's code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller, use a `$scope.$watch()` to perform behaviour when each property changes.

e.g.

```
$scope.$watch('dateStart', function (newDateStart) {
    if (!newDateStart) return;
    $scope.dateEnd = newDateStart;
});

$scope.$watch('dateEnd', function (newDateEnd) {
    if (!newDateEnd) return;
    $scope.dateStart = newDateEnd;
});
```

Note that I would recommend that you first check if there is already a value for the other field, or if the user has manually modified it. If so, don't automatically change the other field. Otherwise, you will be forever overwriting what the user chose for the other field.

Comment: Bonus tip: Consider using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) for date manipulation. It will make your life easier when manipulating dates. In particular, using the `moment().min()` and `moment().max()` will help you constrain your start date to be at or after your end date, or vice versa.